# Devide player into two team by their ratings in angularjs / Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, algorithm

I have an array of players with player name and ratings.

```js
$scope.players = [
  {"name": "Qasim", "rating": "10"}, 
  {"name": "Mahsam", "rating": 10}, 
  {"name": "Aj", "rating": 3}, 
  {"name": "Osman", "rating": 7}, 
  {"name": "Usama", "rating": 7}, 
  {"name": "Bilal", "rating": 3}
]
```

I need to divide players into two team based on their ratings.

```
var playerLength = $scope.players.length,
grouped = _.groupBy($scope.players,function(item){return item.rating});
```

I want to divide players in two team with equal ratting in two balanced teams.

Comment: Do you want something like this: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/wbdzb1vt/)?

Comment: @Rajesh Balanced Team.

Comment: Can you give sample output?

Comment: so in thius situation there will be Quasim + Mahsam vs. AJ, Osman, Usama and Bilal? + how big can the players array and the teams get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to make your teams. I loop over all the players and push the player in the weakest team.

Here is a [**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/v2fyq0mb/), more readable than the snippet.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.players = [{
    "name": "Qasim",
    "rating": 10
  }, {
    "name": "Mahsam",
    "rating": 10
  }, {
    "name": "Aj",
    "rating": 3
  }, {
    "name": "Osman",
    "rating": 7
  }, {
    "name": "Usama",
    "rating": 7
  }, {
    "name": "Bilal",
    "rating": 3
  }];

  $scope.team1 = [];
  $scope.team2 = [];

  $scope.createTeams = function() {
    angular.forEach($scope.players, function(player) {
      if ($scope.teamStrength($scope.team1) < $scope.teamStrength($scope.team2)) {
        $scope.team1.push(player);
      } else {
        $scope.team2.push(player);
      }
    });
  }

  $scope.teamStrength = function(team) {
    var sum = 0;
    if(team.length == 0) return 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < team.length; i++) {
      sum += team[i].rating;
    }
    return sum;
  };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <button ng-click="createTeams()">Create teams!</button>
    
    <h1>Team 1</h1>
    <div ng-repeat="p in team1">
      {{p.name}} ({{p.rating}})
    </div>
    
    <h1>Team 2</h1>
      <div ng-repeat="p in team2">
    {{p.name}} ({{p.rating}})
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var playerArr = {};
var rateArr = []
var leftTeam = [];
var rightTeam = [];

for(id in $scope.players){
    playerArr[$scope.players[id].rating] = $scope.players[id];
rateArr.push($scope.players[id].rating);
}
rateArr.sort();
for(i = 0; i < rateArr.length; i+=2) {
    leftTeam.push({name:playerArr[rateArr[id]].name, rating: playerArr[rateArr[id]].rating});
}
for(i = 1; i<rateArr.length; i+=2){ 
    rightTeam.push({name.playerArr[rateArr[id]].name, rating: playerArr[rateArr[id]].rating;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

A way to do it:

UPDATE: Change has been made to match the question.

```js
var footballers = [
  {"name": "Qasim", "rating": "10"}, 
  {"name": "Mahsam", "rating": 10}, 
  {"name": "Aj", "rating": 3}, 
  {"name": "Osman", "rating": 7}, 
  {"name": "Usama", "rating": 7}, 
  {"name": "Bilal", "rating": 3}
];

footballers.sort(function(a, b){
    return a.rating - b.rating
});

console.log(footballers); //sorted

var team1 = [], team2 = [];

//Assuming, footballers have the same rating twice
for (let index=0;index<footballers.length;index += 2) {
    team1.push(footballers[index]);
    team2.push(footballers[index+1]);
}
console.log(team1, team2);
```

:)

Comment: I need a balanced team .. mean each team have equal ratting in plus

Comment: Okay. Hold on; thinking about it.

Comment: @RamsingNadeem Please read OP's question properly. He wants to divide players in teams in such a  way that their total ratings are equal.

Comment: Updated; didn't pay enough attention to the question.